# Extending a bottom border across multiple inline elements

Tags: html, css

I have a situation in which I have a header and a few radio buttons inline with it that control the contents of what displays below. For style reasons I want the bottom border on the header to extend to the edge of its container, through the following elements.

My situation as of now:

```
<h2 class="header">this is the header</h2>

<label class="l" for="a">this is a label</label>
<input value="a" name="options" type="radio"/>

<label class="l" for="b">this is another label</label>
<input type="radio" name="options" value="b"/>
```

css:

```
label.l{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px;
    color: red;
}

h2.header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline;
    margin: 4px;
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

result: http://jsfiddle.net/F7pzd/1/

Is there a way to get the bottom border to extend all the way across the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `div` element to wrap everything. Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/F7pzd/5/).

Note that by using a wrapping `div`, you can get rid of all the classes you were using previously. Also, note that the `for` attribute for `label` elements needs a corresponding ID.

I've fixed all of these issues in the fiddle example I linked to above.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not add a container element around your h1 and options?

e.g:

```
<div class="border-bottom">
...
</div>

div.border-bottom{
border-bottom: 1px solid blue;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TB8dK/1/

**OR**

You could use `display: inline-block;` and set a static height for all of the elements.
http://jsfiddle.net/yLUC7/5/

(note the use of 'line-height' to vertically align the text in the labels)

Answer (score 1):

First you have to wrap all elements there inside a div or another tag, depends where you want to position elements. In my example i used a `<header>` tag. 
Also it is recommended to put the `<input>` inside `<label>` because is user friendly, they can check it clicking also on text.

You can see my modifies [here](http://jsfiddle.net/stefanz/F7pzd/6/)